# How to show content under a left-sided bootstrap tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to show left-sided tabs, and it would be nice if I could show content under the tabs.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        Tab Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I tried your code and it show me the content below the tabs..

Comment: @Elior ah, sorry, I meant I wanted to show something else under the tabs, not the tab content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another `li` to the bottom of the nav-tabs `ul`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li class="special">Some something here. Show something here.</li>
 </ul>
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://bootply.com/61290)

If you want to customize the look of the content under the tabs use a 'special' CSS class as you'll see in the demo.

Comment: I am also using same code but i could not get this working i would like to have tabs left but its not working. What ver of bootstrap you use ? I use 
TWBS: 3.3.6
JQuery:1.11.3